# Joining by index using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 byte arrays

```
var Bytes =new byte[20];
var Indecies =new byte[20];
```

I just started playing with LINQ and I need to join those to arrays together to create an object.

```
public ArrayObject
{
   public byte index{get;set;}
   public byte value{get;set;}
}
```

So here is how I started

```
var list = from b in Bytes 
           join i in Indecies 
           select new ArrayObject()
               { index=i, value=b }
```

But I cant seem to figure what to put with the `ON` part, in a loop it would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    list.Add(new ArrayObject() { value = Bytes[i], index = indecies[i] });
}
```

How can I join by array index in Linq?

Comment: Why must you absolutely do that with `LINQ`? It seems to be the perfect job for a `for` loop.

Comment: @Vache i just want to know how it goes with LINQ, normally i would go with the loop but i just started learning LINQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the nice `LINQ` syntax, but...

```
var list = Indecies.Zip(Bytes, (i, b) => new ArrayObject() { value = b, index = i }).ToList();
```

You can read about `Zip` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Why not? I feel like that's exactly what he needs from the question, but I might have misunderstood something.

Comment: @Vache yes actually this is what i need, working as it should